# SQL joining three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trouble with joining three SQL tables. For simply think there are 3 table called A, B and C. the table A contains data about attendance such as shift id, date. Other two tables contain data of each shift such as in time, out time. Data of a particular shift can be only included in one table.

table A

```
shift_id  |    date
--------------------
  001     | 2013-12-01  
  002     | 2013-12-01  
  003     | 2013-12-01
```

table B

```
shift_id  | in_time | out_time
------------------------------
  001     | 07:10   | 04:10
  003     | 07:30   | 05:10
```

table C  // does not contains out_time column

```
shift_id  | in_time 
--------------------
  002     | 07:45
```

Expected output

```
shift_id  | in_time | out_time
------------------------------
  001     | 07:10   | 04:10
  002     | 07:45   | 00:00
  003     | 07:30   | 05:10
```

Plz help me.

Comment: have you written any sql?

Comment: even i cant think how to wright.:-(

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c110d/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `UNION` could help you.

```
SELECT 'FROM A', A.shift_id, B.in_time, B.out_time
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.shift_id = B.shift_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 'FROM B', A.shift_id, C.in_time, '00:00'
FROM A INNER JOIN C ON A.shift_id = C.shift_id
```

Comment: it should be C.in_time instead of B.in_time in second select query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming shift_id is foreign key for table B and C, i.e. you don't need to verify if shift_id is present in table A

```
SELECT 
    shift_id, in_time, out_time 
FROM 
    B
UNION  
SELECT 
    shift_id, in_time,'00:00' as out_time 
FROM 
    C
```

else

```
SELECT 
    shift_id, in_time, out_time 
FROM 
    B WHERE shift_id IN (SELECT shift_id from A)
UNION  
SELECT 
    shift_id, in_time,'00:00' as out_time 
FROM 
    C WHERE shift_id IN (SELECT shift_id from A);
```

if you need to verify whether shift_id is present in table A

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IFNULL()` (ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html):

```
SELECT A.shift_id, IFNULL(B.in_time,C.in_time), IFNULL(B.out_time, '00:00') 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.shift_id = B.shift_id 
LEFT JOIN C ON A.shift_id = C.shift_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.shift_id
     , a.date
     , x.in_time
     , COALESCE(x.out_time,'00:00:00') out_time 
  FROM table_a a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT shift_id,in_time,out_time FROM table_b 
       UNION 
       SELECT shift_id,in_time,NULL FROM table_c
     ) x 
    ON x.shift_id = a.shift_id
 ORDER
    BY shift_id;
```